# Include Stack Apps into public data dump

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-dump, stackapps

Now that [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com) is in [public beta](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/stack-exchange-api-public-beta-starts/), should it be included into public data dumps?

---

According to Jeff below, we can revisit this in 4-6 months. Well that time is now here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stack Apps will available in the next data dump downloads.

Answer (score 1):

Yea.

So Say We All.

Answer (score 0):

This won't be necessary until there is more data to work with there.

So, revisit in 4-6 months.

Comment: It's been over 3 months... now can we have it included?

Comment: Revisit in 6 to 8 weeks.