# Data dumps for SE 2.0 betas

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include Stack Apps into public data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/include-stack-apps-into-public-data-dump)

I'm interested in charting the progress of the Theoretical Computer Science beta: how many questions are being asked per day, how many answers, and so on. But more generally, I was wondering if there was any way to get a data dump for our (currently in beta) site much like we can get data dumps for the established sites. Is there any plan to provide this ?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe and that they won't until they graduate.  Some of this data is in the api.  Searching for a link...

Comment: Same deal as Stack Apps, wait until there is more data for them to work with