# Please include Beta Stack Exchange sites in the data dump

Tags: feature-request, data-dump, beta-phase

In this [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/creative-commons-data-dump-sep-11/) it is stated that:

> The latest version of the Stack Exchange Creative Commons Data Dump is
> now available. This reflects all public data in …
>
> - Stack Overflow
> - Server Fault
> - Super User
> - Stack Apps
> - **all public non-beta Stack Exchange Sites**
> - all corresponding meta sites

Could you include the beta Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67433/data-dumps-for-se-2-0-betas), which is itself closed as a duplicate of a much more specific question.

Comment: @Popular Demand I hope it will end as the duplicate's duplicate, there is [some public Beta that are active for more than a year](http://area51.stackexchange.com/?tab=beta)...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the reason is that beta sites could be closed, if they don't respect some parameters; it is probably not worth adding a site when it's not clear if the site will pass the beta phase.

Comment: On the other hand, there is (or was?) a promise to provide a data dump if a site is closed (so all the questions/answers are not lost). If you have to do this anyway, why not include it in the dump?

Comment: Perhaps because generating the dump for a closed site is a one-time-only procedure, not something the team has to do every quarter. @PaŭloEbermann

Comment: @PopularDemand - Isn't generating the dump just a cron job?  With 64 sites and counting, I hope they've got it automated by now...

Comment: @KevinVermeer, yes, there is some sort of [an "automated process"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75101/w/75128#75128), but running it is still ["quite a bit of work for" the team](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/creative-commons-data-dump-jan-11/). As a side note, I see that most of the "new data dump is up" announcement blog posts have been deleted; I wonder why.

Comment: @kiamlaluno - The reason stated [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/include-stack-apps-into-public-data-dump/50838#50838) is that there isn't enough data to be useful.