# Include beta sites in the data dumps

Tags: feature-request, data-dump

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Please include Beta Stack Exchange sites in the data dump](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106802/please-include-beta-stack-exchange-sites-in-the-data-dump)

I just found [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/), that contains data dumps for several SE sites, but [not all](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/). I suspect the inclusion criteria to be "sites that have come out of beta".

Can we include all sites in the dumps, including beta sites?