# When will Mathematica be added to the Data Explorer?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer

I think the [Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) site has ample depth to be added to the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/).

We have 2,988 questions, 6000+ answers, and 2000+ users.  Half the sites represented on the Data Explorer cannot boast these numbers (many of them Metas).  When is my site going to be added?

Comment: This was a feature request in my opinion. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time has come:

https://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/queries

Answer (score 10):

I don't have confirmation this is the case, but I would suspect that Mathematica will be added the next time that Data Explorer receives updates.

This has been held up by the recent slew of hardware and software updates, but it should be [completed once the dust settles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/when-will-data-se-get-updated-data/145732#145732). You can expect more frequent updates then, as well.

Comment: This sounds about right to me.

Answer (score 3):

Beta sites [don't appear in data dumps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106802/please-include-beta-stack-exchange-sites-in-the-data-dump), so they're not included in SEDE. As of the last update ([June 26th](https://data.stackexchange.com/)), Mathematica was still in beta

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't realized (until Tim's answer) that it had been that long since the last update.