# Why is there no option for Astronomy Stack Exchange in data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, data-explorer

And is there a chance that someone might put in that option soon?

Answer (score 14):

[Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) is still in beta.  At the time this was posted, no SE sites would be added to the Data Explorer or the Data Dump until they came out of beta.

Comment: Ok, how long _after_ they leave beta before they show up? One of my users is really curious to run his own queries.

Comment: @jcolebrand  It shouldn't be long.  [Paraphrasing Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50777/include-stack-apps-into-public-data-dump/50838#50838), new sites aren't added until there's a significant amount of data to work with, but Bicycles and DBA should be the next two in line.

Comment: Merci. I told him "just give it another 6 weeks, we just got out of beta" and so that would seem to be in line.

Answer (score 9):

[Astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) is still a beta site, and that is the reason why there is not yet an option for it in Data Explorer. It will eventually added as option, once the site is in beta phase after X days; this is what happened with other sites.
I guess they want to first be sure there is enough useful information, or the site is going to pass the beta phase.

Answer (score 6):

Astronomy is now present in the Stack Exchange Data Explorer.

It has posts from as early as 24th of September 2013.

Today, beta sites *are* added to the Data Explorer once they reach public beta (and once SEDE is updated (usually Sunday morning)), whereas they weren't at the time this question was written.

Roughly over this period [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/astronomy/query/1284160#graph) shows the number of questions and answers created each month for the top 3 tags today.

[image: total question and answer graph]

Enjoy!